# Good article examples of PAF/PCA

Tags: categorical-data, pca, factor-analysis, rotation

Can anyone give me (and probably to the rest of the world) good article examples which uses especially PAF (and/or PCA) factor analysis with oblique and/or orthogonal rotations?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.open-access.bcu.ac.uk/6076/
Advice on Exploratory Factor Analysis- Samuels 2017

https://scholarworks.umass.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1156&context=pare
Best practices in exploratory factor analysis: four recommendations for getting the most from your analysis
Anna B. Costello & Jason Osborne 2005
(this article doesn't have an example but explains concepts in simple terms)

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated! Could you please add DOIs and/or full citations? Links tend to die over time and that would help retain the usefulness of this answer for longer.